# Wix localization file change output directory

Tags: localization, wix

I've added en-us.wxl file to my project. At the moment I do not want to localize it.
I just want to keep all ui strings in one file. And i want to be able to replace the standard text in some dialog without replacing the entire dialog.

For example, change button text in WaitForCosting.dlg from "Return" to "Continue".

But when i rebuild my project, i wondered that output directory changed. In "TargetPath" property was added culture name, like from "Release/setup/" to "Release/setup/en-us".

That's not what i need.
How i can return target path without culture name back? I found no answer in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the WixLocalization/@Culture attribute to an empty string.